# What are some alternative to absolute function that is continuous and differentiable everywhere?

Tags: derivatives, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces, approximation, absolute-value

I'm looking for an L1 norm loss function. But as many of you well know, absolute value is not differentiable at the origin.

But a good alternative function that approximates the L1 norm that is continuous and differentiable everywhere would be good.

By guess is that I would need to create a piecewise continuous function for some arbitrarily small value epsilon such that

if abs(x) > epsilon, then f(x) = abs(x),

else if abs(x) <= epsilon, then some func(x)

What are some functions you can think of that is continuous and differentiable everywhere and is also a good approximation of an absolute function.

p.s.

now, in terms of the "good approximation" for the continuous piecewise function, I would mean, but not necessarily required, is that the smaller the value of epsilon, smaller the value of some distance between func(x) and abs(x) and that the value of epsilon can get arbitrarily small so that it can be used in wide range of applications where the system could tolerate such small arbitrarily small approximation error.

Comment: Try $x \mapsto \sqrt{x^2+{1 \over n}} - {1\over \sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: how would i optimze the value n such that the function is now smooth and differentiable at the junction?

Comment: @KevinKim: You don't need to. There is no "junction."

Comment: Ahh nevermind. This would work. Thanks. I would just need to set n to be as large as the system could handle.

Comment: Just a broad observation gleaned from many years, I have found that tricks like this are useful to get something going, but sometimes suggest that there is something in the underlying problem structure that needs attention or a different technique.